# Trigger PHP function by clicking HTML link

Tags: php, html, function

Is it possible to trigger a PHP function by just clicking a link? Or should I stick with the form submit method? If clicking the link will work, where should the link refer to?

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    function listMe($username){
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO List (Usernames) VALUES ('$username')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>SAMPLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="**__???___**">Add my username to the list</a>
        <?php 
            listMe($_SESSION['Username']); 
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by means of loading the entire page over again by the use of form submission, or by loading specific page contents directly into the page without needing to go from page to page. The second method is called "AJAX" (Asynchoronous Javascript and XML). Here are two examples, one of each specified.

**Form submission approach**

**form.php**

```
<?php
function get_users(){
}
if(isset($_GET['get_users']))
{
    get_users();
}
?>
...
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="get_users">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**AJAX approach**

**ajax_file.php**

```
<?php
function call_me(){
    // your php code
}
call_me();
?>
```

**form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            // do something if the page loaded successfully
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_file.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">click to call function</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm tweaking your code, I'll feedback once it worked. btw I think I can use your code for other cases.. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I left out little pieces that I assume you could fill in yourself, and to prevent myself from writing the whole application for you.

Answer (score 8):

HTML

```
<a href="?list_me">list me</a>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['list_me'])) listMe();
```

Comment: i think you are missing some code in your anchor.  you need href="xyz.php?list_me='me'

Answer (score 7):

(**EDIT** although this works, it's a bad idea as it is. One should never read from `$_GET` without sanitising it first)

You can pass it as a query parameter of the link.
http://example.com/?command=listMe&username=tom
However that way everybody will be able to run the function by loading that URL

```
<a href="http://example.com/?command=listMe&">List me</a>
```

and in the PHP

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['list_me']) && isset($_SESSION['Username'] ) ){
   listMe( $_SESSION['Username'] );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To trigger a function on link click with php the only way I know would be to append a param in the url of the link and then listen for that

```
<a href="?function">Add my username to the list</a>
```

Then check for link

```
if (isset($_GET['function'])){
      runFunction();
}
```

This is because php is a server side technology if you want to fire something without refreshing the page you would need to look at something like javascript

Answer (score 0):

I found this code in a plugin, they have user a foreach look to trigger the action:

```
$actions = unset($meta[$key]);
foreach ( $actions as $action => $value ) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $value['url'] ) . '" class="my-action-' . $action . '">' . '<i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>';
}
```