# OS login php script modification

Tags: php, session, include, login-script

I am trying to modify the following OS login script I found so that when a user has a valid session or "remember me cookie" file A.php is included and if they are not logged in file B.php is included.

I cant seem to solve this simple task on my own ... any help would be great.
Thank you.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

    $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
    $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
    // coookie expiry
    if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

        logout();
        }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

     if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
          session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
        /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
          list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

          $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
          $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

          include('file A.php');
       } 
       else {
       logout();
       }

  } else {
    exit();
    }
}
}

function logout()
{
global $db;
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
mysql_query("update `users` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

include('file B.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this to work if a user has a session or if a user has a cookie yes? If so, the script stops working on the first line.

If the user **has** an active session, the script just stops right there. You would want to move your core code to another function and call it in an else condition.

```
if session exists
 do this
else if cookie exists
 do that
else
 do it
```

You also have an extra } on line 39.

Update -

```
<?
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
    include 'file A.php';
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

    $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
    $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
    // coookie expiry
    if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

        logout();
        }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

     if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
          session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
        /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
          list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

          $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
          $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

          include 'file A.php';
       } 
       else {
          logout();
       }

  } else {
  logout();
}


function logout()
{
global $db;


if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
mysql_query("update `users` 
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= '' 
            where `id`='$_SESSION[user_id]' OR  `id` = '$_COOKIE[user_id]'") or die(mysql_error());
}           

/************ Delete the sessions****************/
unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 

/* Delete the cookies*******************/
setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

include 'file B.php';
}

?>
```

I've changed the exit() to logout(). It may be what you want if the user is not logged in and you still want him to see file B. Otherwise, you can replace it with exit(). Also, note that I've changed the first condition.

What this does is

```
if user has an active session
 show file A
else if user has an active cookie
 if all conditions have met show file A 
 else show file B
else
 show file B
```

Comment: that sounds like a lot bigger of a modification then I thought.

Comment: Not really. Take the second if condition out of the first and replace that with include 'file A.php'. That should do it I believe (not tested).

Comment: let me give it that old novices try

Comment: If the user is not logged in they should see file B.

Comment: Please see if the pseudo code in the updated post above is correct.

Comment: it seems to be working, I need to fix a few errors in my own code because now the logout function seems to be refreshing the page with file B instead of including it.

Comment: Ok I just need to link up   <a href="logout.php" title="Logout">Logout</a> to fire the logout() function now

Comment: Why are you adding a session_start(); in the function? Shouldn't you be doing that at the top of the page? You can't check for the session without starting it. I didn't notice it before.

Comment: theres more code that I didnt add (but yes session_start() is there at the top)
I am going to try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662535/trigger-php-function-by-clicking-html-link to fire the function I need

Comment: Unless you know of a better way of firing the logout() function then using Ajax code?

Comment: Use the HTML, that's the most standard way of doing it. Simply call a url like url.com/logout.php or something

Comment: I have added a call to logout.php and copied the logout code over but now I am getting a 0 error. Trying to debug

Comment: Ok so now it just seems as though the logout function is not destroying the session because I keep seeing file A even though I am firing the logout function.

Comment: Now I am getting PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare page_protect() (previously declared in /file.php:64) in /file.php on line 118

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27461/discussion-between-aventus-and-webmaster-alex-l)

Comment: I have entered alot of information into the chat room. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: it took two 13hr days and some help but after the 3rd rewrite things seems to be working with only one small server causation error that I just will have to live with. This question can be closed. Thank you.